# Making a Azure WebJob run a console application

Tags: azure, cron, webjob

I'm trying to setup a scheduled WebJob (every minute). I've made a Windows Console Application in VS 2019 like this:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace EveryMinute
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://some.url.com");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this request is not important, I just need the url to be triggered every minute.
I can run the exe on my Windows computer. But when I create a WebJob with this exe attached, I keep getting a [failed] notice every minute.

[image: Error response in Azure]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you share the error message that you are receiving (clicking on the link "24 seconds ago..")?

Comment: It sais: A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'D:\Program Files\dotnet'.

I don't know if I can send that dll together with other files in the zip?

Comment: I've published the app in VS, and to my surprise VS asked me immediately if I wanted to publish to a webapp. I did and now it runs with success. Thank you for your push in the right direction!

Comment: @BarendMondt You can add an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the answer visible to others, I'm summarizing the answer as below:

> I don't know if I can send that dll together with other files in the
>   zip?

Yes, we need to add all the contents under Bin/Debug(/net472) path in a .zip file.

[image]

We can also deploy the webjob in vs by clicking publish button.

[image]

If your job fails, you can find the detailed error message in the Run Details.

[image]

[image]